# AWS Cognito as Django authentication back-end for web site

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

My reading of Cognito is that it can be used in place of a local Django admin database to authenticate users of a website.  However I am not finding any soup-to-nuts examples of a basic "Hello, World" app with a login screen that goes through Cognito.  I would very much appreciate it if someone could post an article that shows, step-by-step, how to create a Hello World Django app and a Cognito user pool, and then how to replace the default authentication in Django with a call to AWS Cognito.

In particular I need to know how to gather the information from the Cognito admin site that is needed to set up a call to Cognito API to authenticate a user.

There are two cases to consider: App user login to App, and Admin login to django Admin URL of site.  I assume that I would want to use Cognito for both cases, otherwise I am leaving a potential hole where the Admin URL is using a weaker login technology.

**Current answers on AWS forums and StackExchange either say:**

(1) It is a waste of time to use Cognito for authenticating a website, it is only for access to AWS resources

(2) It is not a waste of time.   I am about to give up.  I have gone as far as creating a sample Cognito user pool and user groups, and of scouring the web for proper examples of this use case.  (None found, or I wouldn't be writing.)

(3) https://github.com/capless/warrant, https://github.com/metametricsinc/django-warrant are two possible solution from the aws forums.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Planning on using Cognito for the federated social login behind a mobile native app and Django server backend.

Really surprised that there isn't at least an auth-backend out there.

Comment: I wanted to use it to make my site look fancy with 2 factor authentication, but it's way too complicated unless they blaze the trail.  I find that the "how to" guides on AWS for Python tend to be quite out of date and they don't put any energy into updating them.  I put the same question on [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=256712&tstart=0) and no Amazon tech has responded yet.

Comment: https://github.com/metametricsinc/django-warrant

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are reading this, you probably googled "aws cognito django" xD.

I just want to share what I did in order to get this thing to work:

- [Django-Warrant](https://github.com/metametricsinc/django-warrant). Great aws cognito wrapper package.
- Make sure to understand your current User model structure. If you use custom user model, don't forget to map it using `COGNITO_ATTR_MAPPING` setting.
- Change your authentication to support 3rd party connectivity. When you get from the client some Cognito token, convert it into your own token using oAuth/JWT/Session.
- **Rethink** your login/register process. Do you want different registration? The django-warrant package supports it...

At the end of the day, this is a **GREAT** solution for fast authentication.

Comment: Thanks for sharing our project and glad it helped you.

Comment: i am very new to django. while trying this i get. Template warrant/login.html not found.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that django-warrant (and warrant) have become unmaintained.  The PyPI versions don't work with Django 2.0.

Comment: The package django-warrant is not in active develoment as of July 2021, Can anyone suggest some alternative package?

Answer (score 5):

To add to the accepted answer, there is a simple but very important extra step that I found was necessary to take to use django-warrant with Django 2.0:

The conditional in backend.py in the root package needs to be changed from:

```
    if DJANGO_VERSION[1] > 10
```

to:

```
    if DJANGO_VERSION[1] > 10 or DJANGO_VERSION[0] > 1:
```

Using django-warrant with Zappa and AWS Lambda:

The project I am working on also uses Zappa to enable the serverless deployment of my Django app to AWS Lambda. Although the above code fixed django-warrant for me when testing locally, after deploying the app to the Lambda environment, I had another significant issue stemming from some of django-warrant's supporting packages - primarily related to python-jose-pycryptodome, which django-warrant uses during the authentication process. The issue showed itself in the form of a FileNotFound error related to the Crypto._SHA256 file. This error appears to have been caused because pycryptodome expects different files to be available in the Crypto package at runtime on Windows (which I am developing on) and Linux (the Lambda environment) respectively. I ended up solving this issue by downloading the Linux version of pycryptodome and merging its Crypto package with the Crypto package from the Windows version.

TLDR: If you want to use django-warrant with AWS Lambda and you are developing on a Windows machine, make sure to download the Linux version of pycryptodome  and merge its Crypto package with the same from the Windows version.

Note: The versions of pycryptodome and python-jose (not python-jose-cryptodome) that I ended up using to achieve the above were 3.7.2 and 3.0.1 respectively.