# Can I replace django admin panel login code by Amazon Cognito?

Tags: python, django, authentication, amazon-cognito

I want to replace admin or superuser login by cognito credentials. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: In the future you should do more research before asking a question.  Also try to specific. I'm not sure if the answer posted below answers your question, but as far as I can tell it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this, you probably googled "aws cognito django" xD.

I just want to share what I did in order to get this thing to work:

- Django-Warrant. Great aws cognito wrapper package.
- Make sure to understand your current User model structure. If you use custom user model, don't forget to map it using COGNITO_ATTR_MAPPING setting.
- Change your authentication to support 3rd party connectivity. When you get from the client some Cognito token, convert it into your own token using oAuth/JWT/Session.
- Rethink your login/register process. Do you want different registration? The django-warrant package supports it...

At the end of the day, this is a GREAT solution for fast authentication.

[AWS Cognito as Django authentication back-end for web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234718/aws-cognito-as-django-authentication-back-end-for-web-site)

Also https://pypi.org/project/django-cognito-jwt/ django-cognito-jwt could help make this easier to setup